# Find the $24$th term of harmonic series $12,6,4,3,\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> How do you find the $24$th term of the harmonic series $12,6,4,3,\cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have $a_1=12$, $a_2=\frac{1}{2}a_1$, $a_3=\frac{2}{3}a_2=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}a_1=\frac{1}{3}a_1$.

Then $a_4=\frac{3}{4}a_3=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}a_1=\frac{1}{4}a_1$.

Each $a_n=\frac{n-1}{n}a_{n-1}=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n-1}a_{n-2}=\cdots=\frac{1}{n}a_1$.

Then you can figure out any term you wish.

Comment: So is the 24th term 0.5?

Comment: it looks like it!